# How can I pass switch parameters from PowerShell to command line instructions?

Tags: powershell

For example, following code tries to run a ROBOCOPY command with 2 switches:

```
function MyCopy($src, $dst, $files, $switches) {
    $res = ROBOCOPY $src $dst $files $switches
    Write-Host($res)    # --> it will show switches ERROR
    return $res
}

$src = "C:\"
$dst = $Env:TEMP
$files = "*.txt"
$switches = "/XO /COMPRESS"

$res = MyCopy $src $dst $files $switches
```

But throws an error when there are 2 or more switches (as in the example):

> ERROR: Invalid parameter #4 : "/XO /COMPRESS"

Probably because PS finds spaces and decides to wrap switches with double quotes.

I know that this intruction could help:

```
param ( [string] $sw1, [string] $sw2, ...)
```

But, does it mean that I need to explicitly DECLARE ALL the parameters that ROBOCOPY could
accept?

Comment: try with `$res = ROBOCOPY $src $dst $files (-split $switches)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can *not* use a *single string* to encode *multiple* arguments** to be passed to an external program.

**Construct an *array***, with **each switch in its own element**:

```
# ...
# Specify the switches as an *array*
$switches = '/XO', '/COMPRESS'

$res = MyCopy $src $dst $files $switches
```

In your `robocopy` call, PowerShell automatically *splats* the array, i.e passes its *elements as individual arguments*.

Note:

- When calling *external programs* such as `robcopy.exe`, [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) of arrays is *implicitly* performed; that is, you can use the `$switches` array as-is, and don't have to (but you may) use `@switches`.
- Note that for options *with arguments* - say what would be `/XF *.txt` in a `robocopy` call with literally specified arguments - the option *name* and *its argument* (value) must be specified in *separate* array elements, e.g. `'/XF', '*.txt'`